# MIN function in SQL Server issues

Tags: sql-server, min

I'm using this query in my Access workspace:

```
cnn_.Execute "UPDATE a SET a.trasco_id_object = b.pratica " & _
                 "FROM trasco_utilizzi_oggetto a, oggetti_pratica b, pratiche_tributo c, denunce_ici d " & _
                 "WHERE c.pratica = D.pratica AND b.pratica = c.pratica AND a.oggetto = b.oggetto " & _
                 "AND b.pratica = (SELECT MIN(b.pratica) FROM oggetti_pratica bb WHERE c.pratica = d.pratica AND bb.pratica = c.pratica AND bb.oggetto = b.oggetto)"
```

but using this I get the following error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Now, the problem I suppose is the `select(min)` that SQL Server 2014 is not liking, but that aggregate is indeed in a select, or am I making a mistake here?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use some proper aliasing, and some proper `JOIN` syntax it makes the problem far far more easy to spot:

```
UPDATE tuo
SET trasco_id_object = op.pratica
FROM trasco_utilizzi_oggetto tuo
     JOIN oggetti_pratica op ON tuo.oggetto = op.oggetto
     JOIN pratiche_tributo pt ON op.pratica = pt.pratica
     JOIN denunce_ici di ON pt.pratica = di.pratica
WHERE op.pratica = (SELECT MIN(op.pratica)
                    FROM oggetti_pratica sq
                    WHERE pt.pratica = di.pratica
                      AND sq.pratica = pt.pratica
                      AND sq.oggetto = op.oggetto);
```

Specifically, notice `MIN(op.pratica)`, but the table is aliased as `sq`. It should be `MIN(sq.pratica)`.

I also doubt that `pt.pratica = di.pratica` is needed in the second `WHERE` (It's already in the `ON`). Thus your query becomes:

```
UPDATE tuo
SET trasco_id_object = op.pratica
FROM trasco_utilizzi_oggetto tuo
     JOIN oggetti_pratica op ON tuo.oggetto = op.oggetto
     JOIN pratiche_tributo pt ON op.pratica = pt.pratica
     JOIN denunce_ici di ON pt.pratica = di.pratica
WHERE op.pratica = (SELECT MIN(sq.pratica)
                    FROM oggetti_pratica sq
                    WHERE sq.pratica = pt.pratica
                      AND sq.oggetto = op.oggetto);
```

*To reiterate my comment: [Bad habits to kick: Using old style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), and in addition [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).*

Comment: you're right, i'm not used to working with joins, but i need to starting use them because the readability is far more convenient. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You're missing that `oggetti_pratica b` is in the outer `FROM` clause, so `sum(b.pratica)` is an aggregation on the outer query.

You probably wanted `bb.pratica`.

```
...
b.pratica = (SELECT MIN(bb.pratica) FROM oggetti_pratica bb WHERE c.pratica = d.pratica AND bb.pratica = c.pratica AND bb.oggetto = b.oggetto)
...
```